# Mock private field with mockito shows no such field exception

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to follow this blog https://newbedev.com/mockito-mock-private-field-initialization
and a lot of stackoverflow questions to mock a private field of a class which is basically another class.

```
    public class Class1 {
 @Inject private Class2 class2;
```

When I use

```
Class2 mockedClass2 = Mockito.mock(Class2.class);
Class1 mockedClass1 = Mockito.mock(Class1.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(Class1.class, "class2", mockedClass2);
```

Or if I use

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(class1, "class2", mockedClass2);
```

Or

```
FieldSetter.setField(class1,  class1.getClass().getDeclaredField("class2")
        , mockedClass2)
```

I get the same error that  **java.lang.NoSuchFieldException**

Does the class have to be static that I am trying to mock? Can anyone suggest what's going wrong. working for the first time with powermockito.

Comment: the exception usually has also a message explaining what is going wrong

Comment: it simple gives the linenumber of failure
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: class2
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
        at test clas line

Comment: in case of whitebox it said 
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No static field named "class1" could be found in the class hierarchy